# Managing/Adding python dependencies in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda, dependencies

I have a question on managing python dependencies in my AWS Lambda package. I have libs like requests, boto3, jproperties. I have added this to the requirements.txt package. But, i also have like logging, setuptools, os etc. Just curious which ones to actually include in the requirements.txt and bundle up and which ones we dont need to explicitly need to bundle up? Any suggestions/thoughts would really help!

Answer (score 0):

`logging and os` are part of Python's standard library. Therefore you don't need to include them in the requirements file. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) the full list of packages included in Python's standard library.

`setuptools` is included in `pip` and pip is installed on the runners that run the lambda function.

BTW `boto3` is also included in the [runtime](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python.html).

In general - `requirements.txt` should include only libraries not part of the standard library.